# Classification Banner for SP2016 on-prem

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem

I'm looking for a way to add a Dynamic Classification banner into an SP2016 on-prem SharePoint site similar to the crude screenshot below.

[image: The ideal outcome of classification banner]

The ideal outcome of classification banner
I've looked into updating the Master Page but I've only been able to get it static, not dynamic (based on the max classification of each individual page.)
The other problem I can envisage is that we use 4 different master pages, so creating something that is page agnostic (hence why it's at the top of the page) is best.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be forever grateful.

Cheers,
Rob

Comment: Hello, what do you exactly mean with classification in this context?!

Comment: Our SharePoint can have things like Commercial-in-confidence, Personal-in-confidence. for example, we have an HR Subsite that would contain Personal-in-confidence documents (payroll info, staff contracts etc)

Comment: Still, didn't get it! what's the relation between this classification and the red bar in your image!

Comment: I'm sorry, I see what you mean... the documents uploaded to the sites get tagged/classified, but ideally, there would be a way for the site as a whole to be classified Commercial-In-Confidence or Personal-In-Confidence (just to name a couple classifications)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own master page with SharePoint designer where you will add this extra panel and with JavaScript you can access SharePoint content so you can have on each web or in list for all definition of the classification.